# Getting &#xed; in place of í, when harvesting/scraping using a Perl script

Tags: perl, character-encoding, web-scraping

I harvested a website using Perl, but I missed something at the start. Now when I start uploading data, I see some strange characters like `&#xed;` and many more alike.
The string is `Líder de Projetos`  but I got `L&#xed;der de Projetos`. I have 40 text files around 50GB together.

How can I fix them without harvesting again?

Comment: Just saying what the edit log says. The edit log does not show bernie deleting anything at all. It just shows him adding the "perl" tag.

Comment: This may be a newbie question that has been asked and answered a lot but keep the following in mind before you down vote. There are plenty of SO questions asking how to decode entity references but there isn't a good one that answers "what does `&...;` mean". This is a tough concept to research from the ground up with a web search because it's nearly all punctuation.

Comment: It's not that hard to research when reading an HTML book. You don't have to learn everything through a web search just at the instant you run into a problem.

Answer (score 3):

The strings of characters that you're seeing are called [character entity references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_entity_reference) or more commonly in this context HTML Entities. They are a way to use the characters that they represent in a limited character encoding that doesn't support the characters. You're seeing this in the place of the accented "i" because when you harvested the content you didn't explicitly tell the "harvester" what to do with these kinds of characters. Maybe the original page used these entity references or maybe the "harvester" assumed that this is what you wanted and turned the characters into entity references.

In order to "fix" these you have to decide exactly what you want to do with this content. I.e.: what is going to use this data. Once you figure that out you have at least a couple of options.

1. Do nothing: if you're sending this content to something that uses a limited character set like ASCII AND knows how to use these entity references then you're probably ok just leaving them in there. For example if you're just using these to generate more web pages then you can leave them as is and they should display properly when the web page is viewed.
2. Decode them using a perl module like [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aEntities): If you know that the thing that you're sending these to can support a Unicode representation (e.g.: UTF-8) then you can use the decode_entities() function from this module to turn these strings into unicode characters. If you do this be aware that some things that you may need to stay as entity representations will get decoded and you may need to reencode them or somehow keep them from getting decoded.

Answer (score 2):

The `&#xed;` is the entity escape for the character with the hexadecimal ordinal value `ED`. Are you sure it's not that way in the source?

If you want to replace those with their character value, use a module to decode them:

```
use v5.10.1;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

use XML::Entities;

my $encoded = "L&#xed;der de Projetos";
my $decoded = XML::Entities::decode('all', $encoded);

say $decoded;
```

Now the output doesn't have the entities:

```
Líder de Projetos
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = undef;
my $file = 'test.txt';

open  FILE, "<$file" or die;
$_ = <FILE>;
close FILE;

s/&#x(..);/{chr(hex($1))}/ige;

open  FILE, ">$file" or die;
print FILE $_;
close FILE;
```

Comment: Always check the results of those calls to `open`. Also, you don't need to slurp the entire file to do this. Notice that he has 50GB of info in just 40 files. And, what makes you think that the ordinal value will only be two characters?

Comment: @briandfoy - I believe everybody here knows `or die;` And 1.25 GB per file is not that bad and this easy and simple code will do it pretty fast - much faster then new "harvesting". And yes, I expect only two character `&#x..;` in Spanish text.

Comment: @briandfoy - I just tested 1.25 GB HTML file and it took only 0.3878 sec. on virtual server

Comment: I don't care about fast. You need to have 1.5GB available to even load the file. It's so easy to do better and you want to work hard to create potential problems. If you believe everyone knows `die`, you haven't been around long enough to see all the questions that don't need to be asked because people don't know to check the return values.

Comment: @briandfoy - I edited my answer and `or die;` has been added. My code is not perfect code for general use, but it solve the problem that author of the question has - I believe he is looking for fast solution of his mistake...